# Framer motion Follow same duration on hover end

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I have an animation that scales the div on hover with duration of `2` which is working correctly. I want same duration to be followed when the mouse leaves the div. Currently the div shrinks instantly to original size.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const variants = {
  hover: { scale: 2, transition: { duration: 2 } }
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <motion.div
        variants={variants}
        whileHover="hover"
        className="card"
      ></motion.div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

There is a `onHoverEnd` prop but it is a function instead. Do I have to manually start another animation in that function?

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-boyd-33v72)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved it by manually stating the start and ending animations with `onHoverStart` and `onHoverEnd`

```
const start = useCallback(() => {
    controls.start("hoverStart");
  }, [controls]);

  const end = useCallback(() => {
    controls.start("hoverEnd");
  }, [controls]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To control on mouse leave transition you define it with transition prop directly on the element:

```
   <motion.div
     whileHover={{ scale: 2, transition: { duration: 2 } }}
     transition={{
       duration: 2,  // duration time when mouse leaves the element
     }}
   />
```